# How does sklearn.feature_selection.RFE eliminate features exactly?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I would like to recursively eliminate features for a logistic regression using sk-learn. Below is the codes I am using.

```
regr = linear_model.LogisticRegression() 
selector = RFE(regr, n_features_final, step=1)
```

However, I was reading the documentation of sklearn.feature_selection.RFE, and on the page it says it uses either coefs_ or feature_importances to do the elimination. In my case, since regr does not return feature_importances_, my guess is that RFE uses the coefs_ to do the elimination. My question is: 1, Does RFE eliminate features based solely on the ranking of the magnitude of coefs_? 2, If so, is it arbitrary to use coefs_ alone to eliminate features?

What I have in mind is to use feature importances or p-values. Can I still use sklearn.feature_selection.RFE to do this?

Thanks!